# How can I reverse py.test addopts?

Tags: python, pytest

My py.test command is attached with extra options fixed. Everytime I run py.test the options are automatically attached.

```
py.test --cov=ner_brands --cov-report=term-missing --cov-config
```

How can I remove these attached options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is there is something specified in your `conftest.py`. See [How to change command line options defaults](http://pytest.org/latest/customize.html#adding-default-options).